# Position Fixed how to fix

Tags: html, css

Consider we have

```
<div style="position:fixed;">Hello</div>
<div>Hi there</div>
```

The fixed positioned div will be removed from the document flow. This will cause the two divs to overlap with each other.
What is the best way to fix this issue? I could use margin-top in the second div, but it seems more like a trick than a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a trick. It is the solution. Or maybe all good solutions are a little tricky. But that is probably the correct one, based on what little you've shown.

That is to say, margin-top of the second div should equal the height of the first.

Comment: what if i don't know the height of the first div?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="position:fixed;">Hello</div>
<div style="position: relative; top: 20px">Hi there</div>
```

change 20px with any size you want